# Can I create the connection between List View Web part to Business Related Web part?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, jquery

Is it possible to create connection between this web part? I want to create the connection between List View Web Part to Business Related web part.

Comment: what do you mean be business related web part, is it a custom web part?

Comment: if you meant business data web part, please ref. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Business-Data-Web-Parts-6ebda742-7563-43a5-9d68-136a00cd4121

Comment: Hey i ref this link but i am not able to connection between List View Web Part to Business Related web part.